# Dynamic Prepared Statement Readymade Function that Prepare Statement ONLY ONCE

Tags: php, mysql, function, dynamic, prepared-statement

> I want a function that prepare statement only once. ( Not every time whenever function called for the same Query ).
>   Because One of Advantage of Prepared Statement is: *preparation on the query is done only once (although the statement is executed multiple times)*

So whenever I call this Function it will Prepare Statement every time and it's not proper because we will miss taking one of the biggest advantage of Prepared Statement. So that, I put the Condition `if( !empty($stmtName) and !isset($GLOBALS[$stmtName]) )` that Check Statement is Already set or not. ( If not then and only then Statement will prepare ) using this we will cover that advantage. **But,** It generates Binding Parameter failed ERROR.

My Function is here...

```
function qryInsert( $stmtName, $table, $field, $params, $formats )
    {

        $query = " INSERT INTO ".$table
                ." ".( (isset($field) and !empty($field)) ? " ( ".(implode(", ",$field))." ) " : " " ). " "
                ." VALUES( ". implode(", ", array_map(function($val) { return "?"; }, $field))." ) ";

        /*if(!isset($con) or empty($con))
        {
            $con = $this->connection();
        }*/


        $a_params = array();


        $a_params = array();

        $param_type = '';
        $n = count($formats);

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
        {
            $param_type .= $formats[$i];
        }

        $a_params[] = & $param_type;

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
        {
            $a_params[] = & $params[$i];
        }

        if( !empty($stmtName) and !isset($GLOBALS[$stmtName]) )
        {
            $GLOBALS[$stmtName] = $GLOBALS['con']->prepare($query);
            // $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        }

        if(!($GLOBALS[$stmtName]))
        {
            echo " Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error; // . " <br> Query : <span style='color:tomato;'> ".$query." </span>"
        }
        else
        {

            if(!(call_user_func_array(array($GLOBALS[$stmtName], 'bind_param'), $a_params)))
            {
                echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->errno . ") " . $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->error;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!($GLOBALS[$stmtName]->execute()))
                {
                    echo "Execute failed: (" . $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->errno . ") " . $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->error;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($meta = $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->result_metadata())
                    {
                        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
                        {
                            $columns[] = &$row[$field->name];
                        }

                        if(call_user_func_array(array($GLOBALS[$stmtName], 'bind_result'), $columns))
                        {
                            while ($GLOBALS[$stmtName]->fetch())
                            {
                                foreach($row as $key => $val)
                                {
                                    $x[$key] = $val;
                                }
                                $results[] = $x;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo " Error occur while Bindig Result...";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $GLOBALS[$stmtName]->close();

        return $results;
    }
```

**INPUT:**

```
qryInsert("insStud", "student_master", array("roll_no","name"), array(21,"Mahetab"), array("i","s"));
qryInsert("insStud", "student_master", array("roll_no","name"), array(8,"Sahil"), array("i","s"));
qryInsert("insStud", "student_master", array("roll_no","name"), array(10,"Mahammad"), array("i","s"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
First time Record will Insert...
After that raised Binding Parameter failed error...
```

**Without this Condition** `if( !empty($stmtName) and !isset($GLOBALS[$stmtName]) )`

*My Code is Work Fine... It havn't any issue... Because It will prepare statement everytime*

> I used $GLOBALS variable so that whenever function called it uses same GLOBALS variable Otherwise function Perform operation with their private variable which doesn't work properly

Comment: "`if( !empty($stmtName) and !isset($GLOBALS[$stmtName]) )` ..My Code is Work Fine... It havn't any issue...", which error have function with this variable so? Have you try to see if the two var is isset/empty before call function?

Comment: I used this condition so if statement is already prepared then it don't prepare second time, Because Prepared Stament's Aim is Prepared Once, Bind Parameter can Multiple and Execute... [ Sorry for poor english ]

Comment: Why do you use `$GLOBALS['con']` when you have a variable `$con` in a function ?

Comment: Because $con variable creates every time whenever function call and it makes a private variable of that function, whereas we want to perform on Global Created $con variable [ May you understand! ]

Comment: A much  simpler yet way more powerful [prepared statement helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) with usage examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved...
Just wants to remove `$GLOBALS[$stmtName]->close();` statement...
Because It closed statement every time function called...
So, that Binding Parameters failed...